# What's the best way to access my Navigation Controller from any one of the views on its stack?

Tags: iphone, ipad

I figured the easiest way is to simply store a reference to the Navigation Controller in each of the View Controllers I push on the stack.  Or, I could just access the AppDelegate from anyone of my View Controllers and grab the Navigation Controller since that's where it's stored.  Both of these approaches just feel awful, as though I'm losing all the benefits of OOP.  This has to be a common issue with anyone building a navigation controller based app.  Your thoughts?

Thanks so much in advance for your wisdom!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Each UIViewController already has a property `navigationController` for this use.  Use `[self navigationController]` to access it.